# Using collection.Map in foldleft

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Can you use collection.Map as the accumulator/return value of a fold?

For example:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(collection.Map.empty[Int, Int]) { 
  case (map, i) => map.asInstanceOf[collection.Map[Int, Int]] + (i -> i)
}
```

Scala gives me the following type error:

```
 found   : scala.collection.Map[Int,Int]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]
              Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(collection.Map.empty[Int, Int]) { case (map, i) => map.asInstanceOf[collection.Map[Int, Int]] + (i -> i) }
```

Why is it enforcing use of `collection.immutable.Map` instead of `collection.Map`?

EDIT: The pointless casting is a bit misleading so I want to make my intent more clear. I am specifically using `collection.Map` inside of the fold because it is the superclass of `immutable.Map` and `mutable.Map`. In reality, I am using a function inside of the fold that returns `collection.Map`, consider:

```
scala> def func(map: collection.Map[Int, Int]): collection.Map[Int, Int] = map
func: (map: scala.collection.Map[Int,Int])scala.collection.Map[Int,Int]

scala> Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(collection.Map.empty[Int, Int])((map, i) => map + (i -> i))
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

scala> Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(collection.Map.empty[Int, Int])((map, i) => func(map) + (i -> i))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.Map[Int,Int]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]
              Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(collection.Map.empty[Int, Int])((map, i) => func(map) + (i -> i))
                                                                                          ^
```

An answer given below does work: changing the start value from `collection.Map.empty[Int, Int]` to `collection.Map[Int, Int]()`. I'm not sure why this makes a difference though:

```
scala> Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(collection.Map[Int, Int]())((map, i) => func(map) + (i -> i))
res13: scala.collection.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit

The method `empty` returns this:

```
def empty[A, B]: immutable.Map[A, B] = immutable.Map.empty
```

That's why you have the error type, so, creating an object with `()`, will return to you the correct type, `collection.Map[Int, Int]`:

```
def func(map: collection.Map[Int, Int]): collection.Map[Int, Int] = map

Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(collection.Map[Int, Int]())((res, i) =>
  res + (i -> i)
)
```

> Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

Comment: This doesn't actually work, the cast is critical to illustrate that I am using collection.Map inside the fold, I'll update the question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: It works as written but it does not work with collection.Map which is what I really want, check the edit for an example of what I mean. Thank you for your answer, my apologies for not making my intent more readily apparent.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to cast it, since you've already defined the type:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(collection.Map[Int, Int]()) {
  case (map, i) => map + (i -> i)
}
```

Comment: The cast was just to force the compiler to use collection.Map instead of immutable.Map. Curiously simply changing from `collection.Map.empty[Int, Int]` to `collection.Map[Int, Int]()` works though

Comment: Scala's collections are immutable by default. To access the mutable versions, you need to import scala.collection.mutable._

Comment: I know they are, I'm asking specifically about collection.Map because I want the superclass of immutable and mutable Maps. I left out this information to keep the question short and clear but I'll add it to make my intent more obvious.

Comment: I have figured out why this works: The return type of `collection.Map.empty` is `immutable.Map` whereas the return type of `collection.Map.apply` is `collection.Map`.